# Corrupt plymouth boot screen when using properietary Nvidia drivers

Tags: 11.04, plymouth

I recently got the final version of **Ubuntu Natty Narwhal x64** and everything is working just fine. The only thing I am having trouble with is the boot screen. After I installed the proprietary nVidia drivers, the boot screen becomes corrupt and only shows text (as it has been doing since Ubuntu 10.04). When I followed the instructions to fix the boot screen in 10.04 and 10.10, the boot screen still remains the same and the problem isn't resolved. Please give a full guide on how to fix this problem.

---

*Machine Details*

Computer : HP Pavilion p6240in

1. Processor : Core 2 duo

   Memory : 4096 megabytes

   Graphics : nVidia G210 3d graphics

Monitor : Dell 17 inch lcd

---

Another question I would like to ask is whether it is possible to use this script (http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html) with 11.04. I am asking this question because it says that the script works only with 10.04 and 10.10.

Comment: post here output of command  grep CMDLINE /etc/default/grub

Comment: about second question, looks like script just add vga=0xXYZW parameter to /etc/default/grub . It should work if it worked for you on 10.10. Grub config stays same, only thing that could changed is graphic driver

Answer (score 3):

I got corrupt boot and terminal screens (white blocks with black lines) when installing 11.04 with an nvidia graphics card, though X server itself was okay.  I fixed the problem by `apt-get install startupmanager`, running startupmanager and increasing the boot screen resolution and colour depth.

Answer (score 0):

Abou script: yes, I have just used for Kubuntu. 
About your problem, I think, you have missed some step, or made typo in cfg file. Recheck it all. The resolution you choose must be available via VBE. Enter GRUB console while booting and command "vbeinfo" to get a list.

Answer (score 0):

Run in Terminal

1.sudo apt-get install v86d

2.gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

3.Replace Line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

New Line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1920x1080-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"

5.Replace Line:#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

New Line:#GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
6.Save & Close

7.gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

8.Add Line: uvesafb mode_option=1920x1080-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
Save & Close

9.sudo update-grub2

10.sudo update-initramfs -u